# How do i build deploy and server a React application locally using Ansible?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, automation, ansible, devops

I would like to install, configure, deploy and serve a local react application using Ansible but i cannot get any valuable information to do it. 
Is there anybody who can guide me on how to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, ansible has a REALLY extensive wiki [here](https://docs.ansible.com/). That will show you the many modules that can be used to do specific tasks. However, this is not where I would start for writing your first playbook, it gets rather daunting.

However, I started and would recommend you start on this [tutorial](https://www.ansible.com/blog/getting-started-writing-your-first-playbook) on how to make your first playbook. you would make a yaml file and run it using the 'ansible-playbook' command on a host that has ssh enabled, ansible installed, and a key pair setup (easily done with ssh-copy-id user@hostname). If you need a way to quickly provision these machines, I personally use Hashicorp's [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to quickly make simple Virtual Machines, however it is possible to use Docker or something else.

As for the specifics for installing specific applications using apt; use the apt module in ansible should serve you right. If you need to install NPM or something of the sort, chances are there's a module for that too. As for copying configs you would want the copy module. Things are pretty straight forward. a good way to structure the google searches to find specific modules would be something like "ansible copy files" and find something from docs.ansible

I realize that this is rather vague; however, I'm not completely sure on your use case in this scenario simply because of the broadness of the question.

Comment: Also do note that writing only playbooks isn't the most intended way to use ansible, instead you are supposed to write roles which consist of different playbooks and etc; however, a good place to start is with just playbooks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your input, it was very helpful.
I finally achieved what i was looking for, and for reference here's how i made it. Hope this is useful for other users.
Assuming you have already installed Ansible in your machine, the following should do the job.

```
    vim inventory
    [appserver]
    127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local

    vim playbook.yml
    ---
    - hosts: appserver
      tasks:
        - name: Installing nodejs
          apt: name=nodejs update_cache=yes
        - name: Installing npm
          apt: name=npm update_cache=yes
        - name: Installing dependencies
          command: npm install
        - name: Building
          command: npm run build
        - name: Installing web server
          command: npm install serve
        - name: Running app on http://localhost:8080
          command: chdir=./build serve -p 8080
```

To run it, just place the following in your CLI

```
sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml
```